# FastAPI/uvicorn not working when specifying host

Tags: python, windows, localhost, fastapi, uvicorn

I'm running a FastAPI app in Python using uvicorn on a Windows machine without a frontend (e.g. Next.js, etc.) so there should NOT be any iteraction between a local frontend and backend like there is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75040507/how-to-access-fastapi-backend-from-a-different-machine-ip-on-the-same-local-netw).  Plus the answer(s) to that question would not have solved my issue/question.  That question was also asked AFTER this one so THIS QUESTION IS NOT A DUPLICATE!

It works fine when I do any one of the following options:

1. Run the following code on my mac, or
2. When I don't specify the port for uvicorn (remove the `host` parameter from the uvicorn.run call)
3. When I specify port '127.0.0.1', which is the host it uses when I don't specify a host at all.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, port=8080, host='0.0.0.0')
```

When I go to 0.0.0.0:8080 on my browser, I get an error that says "This site can’t be reached".

I have checked my current active ports to make sure I'm not getting a collision using `netstat -ao |find /i "listening"` and 0.0.0.0:8080 is not in use.

My current file configuration looks like this:

```
working_directory
└── app
    ├── gunicorn_conf.py
    └── main.py
```

My gunicorn_conf.py is super simple and just tries to set the host and port:

```
host = "0.0.0.0"
port = "8080"
```

How can I get this to work when I specify host '0.0.0.0'?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As I was writing the question above, I found the solution and thought I would share in case someone else runs into this.  To get it to work put "http://localhost:8080" into the web browser instead of "http://0.0.0.0:8080" and it will work fine.  This also works if you're hitting the endpoint via the python requests package, etc.

Comment: This solution works for me too. But It's still kinda magic to me. Why it's work using localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 or 0.0.0.0 ?

Answer (score 15):

Run this in terminal `uvicorn main:app --port 8086  --reload`

Comment: this is it for me.

Comment: this works for me if you want to add this in your debug configuration then just add
--port 8086 --reload

Answer (score 2):

`0.0.0.0` [isn't technically allowed as a destination address in IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0), but can be used as a source address. Implementations vary, e.g. Linux treats it similar to `localhost`.

When testing your web server it is probably a better idea to send requests to `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` as you say.