# How to access FastAPI backend from a different machine/IP on the same local network?

Tags: python, next.js, localhost, ip, fastapi

Both the FastAPI backend and the Next.js frontend are running on `localost`. On the same computer, the frontend makes API calls using `fetch` without any issues. However, on a different computer on the **same** network, e.g., on `192.168.x.x`, the frontend runs, but its API calls are no longer working.

I have tried using a proxy as next.js but that still does not work.

Frontend:

```js
export default function People({setPerson}:PeopleProps)  {
 const fetcher = async (url:string) => await axios.get(url).then((res) => res.data);
 const { data, error, isLoading } = useSWR(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API}/people`, fetcher);
  if (error) return <div>"Failed to load..."</div>;
  return (
      <>
        {isLoading? "Loading..." :data.map((person: Person) =>
        <div key={person.id}> {person.name} </div>)}
     </> 
  )
 }
```

The Next.js app loads the `env.local` file at startup, which contains:
`NEXT_PUBLIC_API=http://locahost:20002`

Backend:

```py
rom typing import List
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends
from ..utils.db import get_session as db
from sqlmodel import Session, select
from ..schemas.person import Person, PersonRead
router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/people", response_model = List[PersonRead])
async def get_people(sess: Session = Depends(db)):
    res = sess.exec(select(Person)).all()
    return res
```

The frontend runs with: `npm run dev`, and outputs

```
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
```

The backend runs with: `uvicorn hogar_api.main:app --port=20002 --host=0.0.0.0 --reload`, and outputs:

```
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:20002 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

When I open the browser on `http://localhost:3000` *on the same machine* the list of `Person` is displayed on the screen.

When I open the browser on `http://192.168.x.x:3000` *on another machine on the *same* network*, I get the "Failed to Load..." message.

When I open the FastAPI swagger docs on either machine, the documentation is displayed correctly and all the endpoints work as expected.

CORS look like this:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

Comment: Have you properly configured CORS on server side, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71805329/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804)?

Comment: I updated the text to reflect the process.env content. And CORS should not be an issue since I configured them like the FastAPI docs suggest. I will consider the links you refer to as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can’t open the console on the other machine. I  tried with my phone as well and it is also giving an error. 

True that I need to print the error instead of what I have here.

Comment: Exactly, that is the problem: the frontend only sees “localhost” even if I connect from 192.168.x.x…

Comment: I understand it is not very clear. I will try to clarify or ask again some other time

Comment: Will do! Thanks a lot. I will report back asap when I get to the code

Comment: Still no luck. I configured CORS with the new origin: `http://192.168.178.23:3000` and enabled an `error.message` display on the screen. On my phone browser, I go to `http://192.168.178.23:3000` and see "Failed to load... Network Error"

Comment: OK. Finally, the trick was adding the new domain to the CORS list of origins AND using that same domain as the address for fetching, ie, loading it in the `env.local` file for the frontend to use

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### Setting the `host` flag to `0.0.0.0`

To access a FastAPI backend from a different machine/IP (than the local machine that is [running the server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73909126/17865804)) on the same network, you would need to make sure that the `host` flag is set to [`0.0.0.0`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0). The IP address `0.0.0.0` means **all** IPv4 addresses on the local machine. If a `host` has two IP addresses, e.g., `192.168.10.2` and `10.1.2.5`, and the server running on the `host` listens on `0.0.0.0`, it will be reachable at both of those IPs. For example, through command line interface:

```py
uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
```

or, programmatically:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

**Note** that [RFC 1122  prohibits `0.0.0.0` as a destination address in IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) and only allows it as a source address, meaning that you can't type, for instance, `http://0.0.0.0:8000` in the address bar of the browser and expect it to work. You should instead use one of the IPv4 addresses of the local machine, e.g., `http://192.168.10.2:8000` (or, if you are testing the API on the same local machine running the server, you could use `http://127.0.0.1:8000` or `http://localhost:8000`).

### Adjusting Firewall Settings

You may also **need** to adjust your **Firewall** to **allow** external access to the `port` you specified, by creating an inbound firewall rule for Python. On Windows, this is usually created automatically, when allowing a program—Python, in this case—to communicate through Windows Firewall, and by default this allows traffic on **Any** `port` (for both TCP and UDP connections).

### Adjusting CORS Settings

Additionally, if your frontend is listening on a **separate** IP address and/or port number from the backend, please make sure to have [**CORS**](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/) enabled and properly configured, as desribed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71805329/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804). For example:

```py
origins = ['http://localhost:3000','http://192.168.178.23:3000']

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

### Making HTTP requests in JavaScript

Finally, please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74407063/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74106637/17865804) regarding using the proper origin/URL when issuing a JavaScript `fetch` request from the frontend. In short, in your JavaScript asynchronous request, you should use the **same** domain name you typed  in the address bar of your browser (but with the `port` number your backend server is listening on). If, for example, both the backend and the frontend server are listening on the same IP address and port number, e.g., `192.168.178.23:8000`—that would be the case when using [`Jinja2Templates`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/) for instance—you could access the frontend by typing in the address bar of the browser the url leading to the frontend page, e.g., `http://192.168.178.23:8000/`, and the `fetch` request should look like this:

```js
fetch('http://192.168.178.23:8000/people', {...
```

For convenience, in the above case—i.e., when both the backend and the frontend are running on the same machine and listening on the same `port`—you could use relative paths, as suggested in a linked answer above. **Note** that if you are testing your application locally on the same machine and not from a different machine on LAN, and instead using `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` to access the frontend/backend, those two are **different** domains/origins. Thus, if you typed `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` in the address bar of the browser to access the frontend page, you shouldn't make `fetch` requests using, for instance, `fetch('http://localhost:8000/people'`, as you would get a CORS error (e.g., `Access to fetch at [...] from origin [...] has been blocked by CORS policy...`). You should instead use `fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/people'`, and vice versa.

Otherwise, if the frontend's `origin` **differs** from the backend's (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71805329/17865804) for more details on `origin`), it should then be added to the list of origins in the CORS settings of the backend (see example above).

Comment: @HenryThornton You can find client-server working examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71741617/17865804)

Comment: @Chris FastApi is used as an http server only. The request is from a Python client for testing but in production, it could be a web client, a native app etc. The listed examples didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

This problem stonewalled me for days - I'm using fastapi/uvicorn on Mac, in Python 3.9.

When setting the uvicorn host to 0.0.0.0, after startup I checked and found that it only binds to TCP 127.0.0.1:

```
sudo lsof -PiTCP -sTCP:LISTEN
```

So I dug into the uvicorn code, the solution was in this file:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/uvicorn/config.py

Simply change this:
sock.bind((self.host, self.port))
to this:
sock.bind(('0.0.0.0', self.port))

After this change I restarted uvicorn and I can access the page from any machine on my network.

Hope this helps someone!