# How to expose FastAPI app to the outside world?

Tags: python, api, fastapi

I've built a simple rest api with just one POST endpoint and I want to send the link  (i.e., `https://mylink/docs`) to a another person who will be sending a POST request to my application.

How do I send them the link? I'm running the app on `localhost` now obviously. I tried accessing `https://my_ip/docs` but it didn't work.

Comment: It seems you need to learn some stuff about networks, hosting, ... you can't just access somebody's laptop like that, either deploy the applicaiton on a server accessible OR configure your local router to make your laptop+port visible from the outside

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75041731/17865804) as well, coupled with the above