# Calling an API works on the computer, but does not work on tablets or smartphones

Tags: reactjs, http, cors, fastapi

I have an SPA with ReactJS and Vite. I am also calling an API made in Python (fast api) in the following code:

```js
const trataClique = async(form) => {
   var myHeaders = new Headers();
   myHeaders.append("token", form.qrcode);

   var requestOptions = {
       method: 'GET',
       headers: myHeaders,  
   };
   setLoading(true)
   const link = "https://someserver:5001/get/endpointx"
   await fetch(link, requestOptions)
   .then(response => {
       alert(`response is:\nStatus: ${response.status}\nStatusText: ${response.statusText}\ntype: ${response.type}`);
       console.log(response);
       return response.json()
   })
   .then(result => {
       setLoading(false)
       //some command
    })
    .catch(error => {
       setLoading(false)
       alert(`THE FOLLOWING ERROR OCCURED: ${error}.`)
        });
    }
```

When I call this function on my notebook or any other, it works fine. But if I try it on a tablet or smartphone, it doesn't work well. I'm afraid this has something to do with CORS policy... can anyone help me?

I tried to change my call (https to http). It did not work in any device.

I also have this in my python code:

```py
app = FastAPI()

# specify who can call API
origins = ["*"]

# allow methods, origins and headers
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

But keeps on failing.

The error shown in console is:

```json
{
    "message":"Network Error",
    "name":"AxiosError",
    "stack":"AxiosError: Network Error\n    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError(http://someserver:5174/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=508d4735:1451:14)",
    "config":{
        "transitional":{
            "silentJSONParsing":true,
            "forcedJSONParsing":true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError":false
        }
        ,"adapter":"xhr",
        "transformRequest":[null],
        "transformResponse":[null],
        "timeout":0,
        "xsrfCookieName":"XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName":"X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength":-1,
        "maxBodyLength":-1,
        "env":{},
        "headers":{
            "Accept":"application/json,
            text/plain, 
            */*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"https://someserver:5001",
            "token":"22222"
        },
        "method":"get",
        "url":"http://someserver:5001/get/check_token"
    },
    "code":"ERR_NETWORK",
    "status":null
}
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75041731/17865804) answer your question?