# FastAPI backend is not working with React Native

Tags: react-native, post, fastapi

API request code I used:

```js
const res = await fetch('http://172.20.10.2:8000/signup', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        credentials: 'include',
        body: JSON.stringify(userInfo),
      });
```

It first takes time and then gives the  error:

> `Network Request Failed'.

I tried it on Postman, all APIs were working. Then I created a whole new backend with express which again worked with react native but FastAPI isn't connecting to react native. Don't know why?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the back-end or the data.

Comment: 172.20.10.2 is a provate IP address, meaning you can only access it from the computer itself. Let me guess, you're testing your react native application from your phone? You need to find your computer's IP address on the local network and use that.

Comment: I'm using an emulator and I used ipconfig command to use the ipv4 of Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75041731/17865804) answer your question?

Comment: You might find  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804) helpful as well