Unable to run Uvicorn server/FastAPI app through Docker
I am new to computer networks and Docker, and I'm trying to deploy and run a small FastAPI app using Docker. The app works successfully when I run it locally with Uvicorn, but it fails to run when I try to deploy it using Docker. Below is the error message. My OS is windows.
I receive:

src/main.py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}

Here is my Dockerfile
FROM python:3.10-slim

WORKDIR /code

COPY ./requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY ./src ./src

CMD ["uvicorn", "src.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80", "--reload"]

Here are the commands I used in the terminal:
docker build -t fastapi-image . 
docker run --name fastapi-container -p 80:80 fastapi-image

here is my docker log:
INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['/code']
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:80 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [1] using StatReload
INFO:     Started server process [8]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.

my file structure:
requirements.txt
Dockerfile
src
|--main.py

requirements.txt
fastapi
uvicorn


What's the docker log look like when you run the container? And file structure in the docker container?

Does this link help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60132045/fastapi-uvicorn-not-working-when-specifying-host It may be an issue when you specify 0.0.0.0 -- try localhost or 127.0.0.1 like the docker log says.

I apologize, but I discovered that I posted the incorrect Docker log file. I have already edited my post to align with the correct Docker log file. Despite trying both of your solutions, they still do not work for me.

When you changed 0.0.0.0 to 127.0.0.1, did you get exactly the same error, ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID? If not, what error did it change to?

for 0.0.0.0 i got "ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID" but for 127.0.0.1 i got "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

your code works fine ...  http://localhost/  ... or use   curl http://localhost/  ... as viewed from my Ubuntu laptop

As others have said, 0.0.0.0 is a valid listening address, but an invalid connection address. 0.0.0.0 means that the server should listen on "all addresses on interfaces". 127.0.0.1 and localhost are the local ("loopback") interface, your own machine

Maybe you have something conflicting? Do a docker container ls (that's an el, not an "i") and make sure nothing is listed. Then try to connect and make sure you get a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED or something similar. Then restart your docker container (docker run --name fastapi-container -p 80:80 fastapi-image) and see if it works now when you attempt to go to http://127.0.0.1

You might find this answer helpful.

By replicating the issue, can see the result at localhost:80.
See also these posts to know more about the differences between localhost and 0.0.0.0:

What is the difference between 0.0.0.0, 127.0.0.1 and localhost?
https://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1

